# How to find number of matching values with an ID?

Tags: excel

I have a unique list of IDs of people on two separate sheets. One for initial 'registration data' which is the master data list. In column A is the ID, column B is their town of residence and column C is the date in which the person was added to the list.

I send out sheets to the different towns every month to receive some more data about the new people added to the list, and every month (the same month) they should send it back to me. This received data goes onto a second sheet, with again: column A for person, B for town, and C for month data received.

I need to check how accurate the towns are in getting the data back to me on time. So I need to count the number of forms on the second sheet where the month is the same as the initial month on sheet number one, and the towns match too.

I have tried COUNTIFS with VLOOKUPs but am having no luck. I want to avoid having to make an interim data table as much as possible because I need the process to be slick and automatic.

Could this be done with a SUMPRODUCT?

For example:

```
Sheet 1 (initial)             Sheet 2 (received)
123, TownA, Feb                 123, TownA, Feb
124, TownB, Feb                 124, TownB, Mar
127, TownB, Mar                 127, TownB, Mar
130, TownC, Mar                 130, TownC, Mar
220, TownC, Apr                 (we didn't receive back 220)
```

OUTPUT SHEET

Feb                    Mar                 Apr
TownA  1                      0                  0
TownB  0                      1                  0
TownC  0                      1                  0

As you can see, of the five forms we only received three in the month we were supposed to. I want it in the view above, and don't really want to have to make a new sheet with the IDs to match the months up.

Comment: Have you considered a database to keep track of our data since you can easily run queries to get the desired results. Also if you want some other data retrieval in future a database query would be much easier than devising excel formulae.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply :-) Unfortunately a database isn't feasible in the time left I have to get these figures out. I'm producing the above for stats about the quality of the data, but the rest of the process has been developed by myself in Excel VBA, and the sheets sent back to me have been generated by a form for each unique ID. Turning this into a database would be time consuming and also wasn't on the job spec as they wanted Excel - although I agree it'd be useful for this type of data retrival. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sheet3 with `Feb` in C1, `Mar` in D1 and `Apr` in E1 and `123` etc in A2 etc, in B2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

in C2:

```
=(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A))=C$1)*(INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A))=C$1)
```

C2 copied across to E2 and B2:E2 copied down to suit.

Then select A:E and DATA > Subtotal At each change in: (ColumnB), Use function: Sum, Add subtotal to: check Feb, Mar, Apr, Summary below data and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Copy A:E, Paste Special, Values over the top and apply filter. Filter ColumnB, Text Filters, Custom Filter..., contains `Tot`, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

In the first populated cell in ColumnB enter `=Bn` (where `n` is the row number immediately above that cell, though not visible) and copy down to suit.

Hide or delete the totals row to suit.